# Is "input" a keyword that causes errors when used as a parameter name (in PyTorch)?

Tags: python, pytorch

So I have a line of code:

```
packed_embeddings = pack_padded_sequence(input=embeddings,
                                                 lengths=lengths,
                                                 batch_first=True)
```

That throws me this error:

```
  File "/Users/kwj/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/onnx/__init__.py", line 130, in might_trace
    first_arg = args[0]

IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

But magically fixes itself if I take out the "input":

```
    packed_embeddings = pack_padded_sequence(embeddings,
                                             lengths=lengths,
                                             batch_first=True)
```

Here is the function specification in the PyTorch docs:

https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/_modules/torch/nn/utils/rnn.html#pack_padded_sequence

I'm using Python3 and PyTorch 0.4. Am I missing something really basic?
Not sure if this is my issue, or a PyTorch specific issue...pretty confused here.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What's happening here is that `pack_padded_sequence` is decorated to return a partially applied function, and within the decorating code there is a function that accepts arguments as `*args, **kwargs`. This function passes `args` to another function, which inspects the first `arg`.  When you pass all the arguments to `packed_padded_sequence` as keyword arguments, `args` is empty, and so `args[0]` raises an `IndexError`.  If you pass `input` as a positional argument,`args` is not empty, and the `IndexError` is not raised.

This example code demonstrates the behaviour (the Pytorch [code](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/3749c581b79cba49f511b19fa02c0f50fa05b250/torch/onnx/__init__.py#L130) is not easy to read).

```
def decorator(func):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        print('Args:', repr(args))
        print('Kwargs:', repr(kwargs))
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper   

@decorator
def f(a, b=0, c=0):
    return a, b, c


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print('Positional argument...')
    print(f(1, b=2, c=3))
    print('All keyword arguments...')
    print(f(a=1, b=2, c=3))
```

The code produces this output:

```
Positional argument...
Args: (1,)                        <- Args is populated
Kwargs: {'b': 2, 'c': 3}
(1, 2, 3)
All keyword arguments...
Args: ()                          <- Args is empty
Kwargs: {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}
(1, 2, 3)
```